# Image not showing in payment options checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I want to change the image on payment gateway options in checkout page in woocommerce, i changed the url in php file but it doesn't show either, can you help me with the problem, below is the code and images, the code is in line 55;
https://privatebin.net/?710d36d1c15d5382#4jmp9RDb5fY4eckeLK2xW8knY6eMRP4DDPi2opmWSwXz
https://privatebin.net/?3d3609ea7979c3a7#2ffND84gXLdhuWiGVAb8nA4un6qsziftsEG2UmydNEs6
https://privatebin.net/?582d61ae5173714b#EzQczuTofXf3TaQNPFtHyJnJShdyD86GojxuPHKowRdk

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

in the URL you have `gateway\images` but you actually put the image inside the `\images` folder. either move the image to the correct location or fix your image url.